# Botones "Prev","Next" en datepicker no se ven

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Tengo un datepicker en el que las flechas para navegar entre meses no se ven, aunque si paso el mouse me muestra el titulo pero no se ve la flecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 $('.date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
}).prop('readonly', true);
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la estructura de tu aplicación y un pantallazo de la consola (F12)? Seguramente no está encontrando los iconos en tu proyecto.

Comment: También puedes inspeccionar el elemento con F12 y ver de dónde trata de obtener el icono.

Comment: @Kiko_L Te refieres a esto 404 Not Found ui-icons_444444_256x240.png

Comment: Eso es. Te está diciendo que no encuentra las imágenes de los iconos. Mira a ver en qué ruta los está buscando (en las propias herramientas del desarrollador te lo dirá (F12) y si no en tu .css)

Comment: Solucionado, agregue los recursos (ui-icons) faltantes en la carpeta public/images